# JSON string after select

Tags: php, jquery, json, .post

How can create a string in JSON after a  mysql select:

```
$ritorno = '{"Prodotto":'.$riga['Prodotto'].',"Prezzo":'.$riga['Prezzo'].'}'
```

and return this:

```
{"Prezzo":24.00,"Prodotto":Chiavetta Usb Moskeyto 8 gb}
```

But I can't insert in my input field

**Jquery**

```
function chiama(elemento){
      var $code_bar = $("#code_bar").val();

      $.post("return.php", 
            { code_bar: $code_bar },
      function(data) {
            $("#Prodotto").val(data.Prodotto);
            $("#Prezzo").val(data.Prezzo);
    }

      , "json");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn php array to json formatted string.

Example from manual:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
// prints {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any other element on that `$riga` array then you can just do

```
echo json_encode($riga)
```

and if you have other elements on that array and just want those two to be json encoded then you can use

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "Prodotto" => $riga['Prodotto'],
    "Prezzo" => $riga['Prezzo']

   ));
```

The reason your one is not working is because you dont have the `string value` in `quotes`
Which is required for valid `JSON`

You have to do it like

```
$ritorno = '{"Prodotto":"'.$riga['Prodotto'].'","Prezzo":'.$riga['Prezzo'].'}';
```

If you insist to go in your way.

But using `json_encode` is better.

**Example Code:** http://codepad.org/r6D7z9TF

Comment: Sorry Joy, I can't again populate my input field, I've use this code: echo json_encode(array(
    "Prodotto" => $riga['Prodotto'],
    "Prezzo" => $riga['Prezzo']

   ));

Comment: {"Prodotto":"Chiavetta Usb Moskeyto 8 gb","Prezzo":"24.00"}{"Prezzo":24.00,"Prodotto":Chiavetta Usb Moskeyto 8 gb}

Comment: Can you check, your `console` if it's throwing any error, or `net tab` in firebug to check what data is being returned, or give me any url so I can check.